# Difference between pimpl and defining class inside .cpp file

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

Im trying to understand difference between pimpl and defining inside .cpp file

```
// foo.h - header file
#include <memory>
class foo
{
public:
    foo();
    ~foo();
    foo(foo&&);
    foo& operator=(foo&&);
private:
    class impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> pimpl;
};
// foo.cpp - implementation file
class foo::impl
{
public:
    void do_internal_work()
    {
        internal_data = 5;
    }
private:
    int internal_data = 0;
};
foo::foo()
    : pimpl{ std::make_unique<impl>() }
{
    pimpl->do_internal_work();
}
foo::~foo() = default;
foo::foo(foo&&) = default;
foo& foo::operator=(foo&&) = default;
```

and

```
// foo.h - header file
#include <memory>
class foo
{
public:
    foo();
    ~foo();
    foo(foo&&);
    foo& operator=(foo&&);

};
// foo.cpp - implementation file
class impl
{
public:
    void do_internal_work()
    {
        internal_data = 5;
    }
private:
    int internal_data = 0;
};
foo::foo()
{
    impl _impl;
    _impl.do_internal_work();
}
foo::~foo() = default;
foo::foo(foo&&) = default;
foo& foo::operator=(foo&&) = default;
```

and I see no benefit of using pimpl, because implementation is already hidden from viever in cpp file, and even he don't know a name for an internal class with do real work.

Comment: Add a member function `get_data` (returning the internal data) to `foo` and try to incorporate that into your second code example ...

Comment: `impl _impl` inside your constructor only lasts until the constructor is finished, then your _impl variable is cleaned up and you can never use it again. With pimpl, you DO define the class in the .cpp file.  You forward declare it and hook up a const unique_ptr to it in the header file -- but that's pretty much all that goes in the header.  Make sure you define the destructor in the .cpp file as well, in order to not get incomplete type errors in the auto-generated destructor.

Comment: In your second example, *where* is the variable `_impl` defined? What is the *scope* and *lifetime* of it?

Comment: In second case _impl is defined in .cpp, and its lifetime is same as the constructor of foo goes away, with is desired in my app becouse object of foo and impl are only needed once, and then it should call destructors. Pimpl was used only to hide impl. So in such circumstances its even a bug to preserve object of _impl. So pimpl should be used to PRESERVE object, and defining it in cpp to dont?

Comment: If you only need to do something once in the constructor and then not ever again during the `foo` objects lifetime, then pimpl is the wrong idiom for you. Instead I suggest either a private member function (if you need access to private members) or a function in an anonymous namespace (so it's local in the source file). No need for classes or structures.

Comment: Private member and fields are not desired because its part of a larger program, and such approach was made to reduce compilation time. Class of impl is needed because all implementation of foo goes there (with is rather large), to optimise for time compilation. Nevertheless all comments contains answer for question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a field to `foo`, then in the second case it has to be defined in the header (as well as field's type), but in the first case (pimpl idiom) you can define field in `impl` instead, and its instance will live as long as `foo`'s instance.